# Last few addresses on RAM module confirmed bad what to do

Tags: windows-vista, memory

So I have 6GB of corsair dominator DDR3 1600 about 2 years old.

Repeated memtest 86 reports show the last few addresses around 1980 - 2048 are bad.

Had constant BSOD when booting even to the vista install disk, removing the first module clears the problem.

Wondering if I can move this module to the last in the series and be ok 90%+ of the time.

Wanted to know if the mem management in vista uses ram sequentially or its random. If its random guessing I am sol and will have to either live with 4GB or buy a new stick.

If this was your PC what would you do?

Comment: Buy new RAM. It's cheap, like @ultrasawblade said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows randomizes where it assigns things to RAM, except for a few well-known DLLs that are always loaded at static locations (this might have changed since Vista).  This is done for security.  Linux does this too.

Now Linux has a feature called BadRAM where you can specify specific addresses not to allocate.  Windows doesn't that I know of, although you can set a memory limit in the boot-time parameters - that could help you.

Buy new RAM.  It's cheap these days.

Comment: Check the warranty first, some RAM is guaranteed for life.